# Trying to understand the [ ] in Python

Tags: python

I learn Python and I saw the following code. This code refers to: Creating an array with 100 random values between 0 and 1. Moreover, determine the value of the entry that is the largest value of all entries whose index is divisable by 2.

```
var1 = numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)

var2 = numpy.arange(0, 100, 2)

var3 = var1[var2]

print(var3[numpy.argmin(var3)])
```

However, I do not entirly understand line 2 and 3 of the code. Can someone clarify this? Why do we create line 2? And what does `var1[var2]` mean?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to start with the Python basics before jumping into numpy. Slicing and indexing using `[]` are basic Python operations. You probably want to start there and work your way up to numpy and others.

Comment: `var1` will be a list of random numbers. `var2` is an even number between 0 and 100. `var2` will be the element at index `var2` inside list `var1`. Basically it is `list_of_values[index_in_list]`.

Comment: @JQadrad no **it won't be a list** it will be an array. `list` objects won't work like this

Comment: Apologies. You are right. `var2` will be an array of numbers and will select all the all the values from `var1` on the even indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the brackets refer to an index within the list var1. For instance, if I have the list `nums = [0, 1, 5, 4, 2]`, `print(nums[2])` would yield an output of 5.

Comment: `nums` isn't an array. It is a list.

Comment: misspoke whoops. Too much java work recently @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: `var2` is not a single index. It's an array of 50 values.

Answer (score 1):

var3 = var1[var2] means you are taking both the values from the object and referencing it to variable 3
same as this:
line 2:

```
var2 = numpy.arange(0, 100, 2)
```

makes an array from 0 to 100 with a difference of two each.

import numpy as bumpy
   var2 = numpy.arange(0, 100, 2)
   print(var2)
The Output of the code will be:
import numpy as numpy
var2 = numpy.arange(0, 100, 2)
[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18...........................,98]

You can delete the reference to a number object by using the del statement. The syntax of the del statement is −

```
del var1[,var2[,var3[....,varN]]]]
```

You can delete a single object or multiple objects by using the del statement.

Comment: `import numpy as bumpy` - why would you do such a thing?

Comment: I think it is a typo, because the second time he does `import numpy as numpy`

Comment: That's weird in a different way, because it could have just been `import numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class you can define

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    ...
```

As you want. Numpy array also overrode the **getitem** method, there is a few ways you can use it.

In case of np.array[np.array], the second array contains indices, that we choose from first array (here - every second element).

Answer (score 1):

So first you have to understand what *np.arrange()* does ?

=> *np.arrange()* is one of the array creation routines based on the numerical ranges . It created an instance of *ndarray* with evenly spaced values and return the references ti it .

***Syntax : numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ], dtype=None) -> 
            numpy.ndarray***

1. The first three parameters determine the range of the values, 
   while the fourth specifies the type of the elements:
2. Start is the number (integer or decimal) that defines the first 
   value in the array.
3. Stop is the number that defines the end of the array and isn’t included in the array.
4. Step is the number that defines the spacing (difference) between each two consecutive values in the array and defaults to 1.
5. dtype is the type of the elements of the output array and defaults to None.

Now if we look in the code for line 2 :

*var2 = numpy.arange(0, 100, 2)*

```
>>> np.arange(start=0, stop=100, step=2)
array([0, 2 , 4)
```

In this example, start is 0. Therefore, the first element of the obtained array is 0. step is 2, which is why your second value is 0+2, that is 2, while the third value in the array is 2+2, which equals 4.

It will go till it reaches 100 i.e "*stop*".

Then lets go on the 3rd Statement :

*var3 = var1[var2]*

It says that it is list_of_values[index_in_array]

If you still got any doubt feel free to ask i will definitely try to resolve it.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. It is very clear, but I still don't understant `var3 = var1[var2]` does this mean that `var3` is a list of values from `var1` and `var2`? Or does it mean, we look at similar values between `var1` and `var2`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply var 2 represent array of index which contain even numbers from 0-100 and in the code they have passed *var2* in *var1* .

***var3 = var1[var2]***

The above statement says that when we run the code the value of var 2 will be check in the var1 at that particular index and if we found the vale then it will be passed in var3.

**Let's us understand with example :**

Suppose the first value in *var2* is 1 i.e index so it will check the value at index 1 in *var1* and if found it will retrun it to the new array i.e *var3*.

Hope you will understand it but still if get any doubt you can resolve it anytime from me.